# Update data row wise till last row using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have Two excels.
Excel1 have 7 columns out of which 3 are filled. Excel2 is also having 7 columns all filled.
1st 3 columns of Excel2 have data from Excel1. Excel1 is having around 50 rows, while Excel2 is having 10 rows.
I want to update all the data from Excel2 to Excel1 (update entire row)
I want to update those 10 rows to Excel2 (which is already having 1st 3 column's data from Excel2). While updating row Macro should check 1st three column's data (It should match exactly).
Please help.

I tried to write code here
But it's showing formating error.     Sory for it that i could upload it here.

Comment: Are `Excel1` and `Excel2` workbooks or worksheets?

Comment: Could you show us the code that you have so far?

Comment: @AlexP : Excel1 and Excel2 are different workbooks

Comment: @rwisch45 Sub Macro3()
' Macro3 Macro
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Range("C2").Activate
    Selection.AutoFilter
     Flname = InputBox("Enter File Name :", "Creating New File...")
    Windows(Flname).Activate
    Range("B1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("testing1.xlsm").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$H$35").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=abc", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Windows("dfg.xlsx").Activate
    Range("D1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("testing1.xlsm").Activate

continue----->

Comment: ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$H$35").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:= _
        "=15-Jun-13", Operator:=xlAnd
    Windows("dfg.xlsx").Activate
    Range("E1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("testing1.xlsm").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$H$35").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="=a", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Windows("dfg.xlsx").Activate
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Range("E1").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("testing1.xlsm").Activate
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

Comment: Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub                                 Please consider dfg.xlsx as Excel2 and testing.xlsm as Excel1

Comment: Hurreeyyy It's done.... I used do until loop for it

Comment: Are you trying to update data from `Excel2` into `Excel1` where the first 3 columns on `Excel2` match the first 3 columns of `Excel1`?

Answer (score 0):

Its done...
I used Do until loop as follows :

```
Sub Macro6()
    Dim rw As Integer, clm As Integer, clcnt1 As Integer, clcnt2 As Integer, clmcnt As Integer
    Dim str As String, str1 As String, str2 As String
    rw = 1
    clm = 1
    clmcnt = 0

    Do
        clcnt1 = Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row
        Rows("1:1").Select
        Range("E1").Activate
        Selection.AutoFilter
        Range("B" & rw).Select
        Windows("dfg.xlsx").Activate
        clcnt2 = Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row
        clmcnt = cntcnt + 1
        str = Cells(rw, clm + 1).Value
        Selection.Copy
        Windows("testing1.xlsm").Activate
        ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1:$E$" & clcnt1).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=str, Operator:=xlAnd
        Windows("dfg.xlsx").Activate
        Range("D" & rw).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Windows("testing1.xlsm").Activate
        Range("D" & rw).Select
        str1 = Cells(rw, clm + 3).Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1:$E$" & clcnt1).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=str1, Operator:=xlAnd
        Range("E" & rw).Select
        Windows("dfg.xlsx").Activate
        Range("E" & rw).Select
        str2 = Cells(rw, clm + 4).Value
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Windows("testing1.xlsm").Activate
        ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1:$E$" & clcnt1).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=str2, Operator:=xlAnd
        Windows("dfg.xlsx").Activate
        Rows(rw).Select
        Range("E" & rw).Activate
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Windows("testing1.xlsm").Activate
        Rows(rw + 1).Select
        Range("E" & rw + 1).Activate
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Range("E" & rw).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.AutoFilter
        rw = rw + 1
        clcnt2 = clcnt2 + 1
    Loop Until rw = clcnt2
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: am facing one problem with this now... it is updating rows directly in sequence rather than filtered rows ! :-( how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Hey its done now...
I used following code to get row number of filtered data then updated required with reference to this row number
`ActiveSheet.Range("$B$2:$E$135").Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Row`

Thanks to all for help